# Not able to resize texarea in IE11 using angular js directive

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

Textarea is resizable in FF and Chrome but not able to resize it on IE 11. Trying to create angular js directive on the basis of jQuery UI resizable but no luck.

```
angular.module('xyzApp').directive('textarea', function() {
    return {
        // A = attribute, E = Element, C = Class and M = HTML Comment
        restrict:'E',
        //The link function is responsible for registering DOM listeners as well as updating the DOM.
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.resizable();
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but FF and Chrome have resizable textareas built-in, so what might be happening is that the plugin isn't working and is only apparent on Internet Explorer (since I don't think IE has built-in resizable textareas). There's a lot of reasons for the plugin to not work, and it's hard to say without seeing more of your code, but one quick thing you could try would be to wrap the Angular element in jQuery. That is:

```
$(element).resizable();
```

I've run into a couple of cases where jQuery code didn't want to play nicely with the elements that Angular was providing. Anyway, I hope that helps!